# Why doesn't this list comprehension in haskell include lists of size < n

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am looking at this code for generating combinations in Haskell

```
combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinations 0 _ = [[]]
combinations n xs = [ xs !! i : x | i <- [0..(length xs)-1] 
                                  , x <- combinations (n-1) (drop (i+1) xs) ]
```

I tried to visualize how the tree gets expanded, but I do not understand why the list doesn't include the paths in red.

[image]

```
combinations 3 "abcd"
["abc","abd","acd","bcd"]
```

All I can see is `xs !! i : x` ie append the i'th element to the n  -1 combinations of it's tail, but why doesn't `[d] : [[]] = [d]` get included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is this: “isolate” each element in the list from the rest, then recurse over the rest. You attempt to achieve this seperation by, on one side, *selecting* each element with `!!`, and on the other *removing* it. But that's not quite what `drop` does, it's rather a task for `deleteBy`. That is awkward to use with indices, though:

```
combinations n xs = [ xs !! i : x | i <- [0..(length xs)-1] 
                                  , x <- combinations (n-1) (xs' i) ]
 where xs' i = snd <$> deleteBy ((==i).fst) (zip [0..] xs)
```

*In general* it's rather unidiomatic to index into Haskell lists. A much better approach is to implement this isolation-thing by direct recursion:

```
foci :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
foci [] = []
foci (x:xs) = (x,xs) : map (second (x:)) (foci xs)
```

And then you can do

```
combinations n xs = [ x₀ : xs'' | (x₀,xs') <- foci xs
                                , xs'' <- combinations (n-1) xs' ]
```

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, that could be the `second` from `Data.Bifunctor` or the one from `Control.Arrow`. Since the `Bifunctor` abstraction is considerably easier to grasp, I'd go with that one.

Answer (score 1):

`drop (i+1) xs` does not remove the `i+1`th element, but all the elements with index `< i+1`.

Comment: Yes I know what drop does I still can't find where my logic is wrong though